# Power BI Developer Samples Demo App Running Infinite Loop On Authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to build a Power BI embedded app using the Power BI Developer Samples provided by Microsoft. I have downloaded the sample code from [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20organization) and followed the instructions in the ReadMe. I registered an app in Azure AD, added the redirect URI and added the client ID and client secret to the appsettings.json file. When I run the app, it says "Sign in to Power BI", as expected. However, when I click the Sign In button and enter my credentials it ends up continually sending requests on an infinite loop. At first, it tries to load the following page:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?<params>`

This goes on for a while and in the debug console, I just see "BadRequest" on this request over and over: `Sending HTTP request POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Eventually, it starts sending reprocess requests over and over like so (and showing nothing in the debug console):
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/reprocess?ctx=rQQIARAAFZK_j9t0AMWTy116Pan0gAohBNIJdUAFJ9_E_vpHpErY8SXOJbYvthOfs1i2Y8ffi3_FcZzE_wCMhanqABJIiF8DYkKdmDrcVARDxc5SCVEhobYbqZ7ee3rLmz5H12AN1kAN3Kk0a6B1e0pCSJAWhRG442KE7eGYRdMMBmicpK0p6RFTkL5xdPzF_ck3f9z6uP_5f-fvLmsndx6Ub8TpzIpQYWUojpa_lMuPy-Xv95YkTuOQpCmKJHFq9wGatYlubA2tg2RNzIzLES4hAMRwhA80H4k8mxnFbD3hp6HEs9AIxbWkd-ZSMdl5lsmagiZtAGSNJQb66a6NTNTHobj7lMKdtPHln3s3ZXaV-c1XEaeocP_du-7FaWgm8TJ7UHm01_b4M7o_W5ucYCsXG2HBIaAChc43blvubJJwGsa0pbIrlnB0egW7S47VBoxtowFnkqh_WZC5rOgeGWy8kE5zpqE6ojDfropYEDqcjfg-Ga2bqjPpKRblGH6aD0YdYJ2ltp-F9lbPZEKAHHum2LwlqdDVLZefJK6Sz7qCGVGuIbIEmo0uLCzvC-74HJqMGHSmE2GeGNDAZeCdBtQ43zI92lEB7KoLTtPldqHKDW4ISWOxJn3KPCsoaPoozpq9AQNpA5OktSCrHVNfbZHC-pYcY6lQrEZ5v-9oI7QmxqOulVDkcMPOM27aHcKV5GGNWBWGc8btpRFb4AG3SeNTfREOf65UnTgM4-hh5TYFgNuk3QYGCMfbwdN0MNr2KKzBkMAjSJfxPHhVeS9O3AhNT2LPC1DkmpbjuMvlSZLGHgrcx_vlp_tvHR4cH7xdOil9cAtUWoeHR8elV-vFfvmrgx13z_4yv_1x_0n3639-e6f47Hnp6qBOemldDRrIHVi4NIFg_iG1DXow2ygyKcmJukglPQy48wt7fhe2Gveq5XvVN6-qr_d4UzrVVI3dcabwTRM8q-KfXis9vP6-n2XJslWvB7FjBf6OmRYEANSXaBahCIvR1Ll_VP71RunFa5_8_uV3Pzx6-bfw9OZHl8k2v2AUxe3nSipyjrDmdWfBp-55v00211ZYn_tS0e3m7vDuT8el_wE1&sessionid=700e28e1-04cf-432c-8bf7-1960f46e9ff5` constantly changing the "ctx" value.

I have tried clearing my cache and it still did not work. I've double checked that I followed the instructions from the ReadMe and I don't think I missed anything. Other than entering the ClientId and ClientSecret into AppSettings, I have made 0 changes to the sample code so I'm not sure why it would not be working properly or at least catching an error other than "BadRequest". Any help/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Madhav - I tried using an incognito window and also a different browser and still had the same issue. For revoking user access, the authentication is for logging into Power BI, not for logging into the app. So it is not an issue of having access to the app itself

Comment: Faced Similar issue while running the .NET samples but it turns out that the issue is with the Azure application and the config. When I grant admin consent to my API permission, its working fine.

Comment: Please cross check your azure application and let me know if you're still facing the issue